# Related entries using Playa

Tags: playa, relationships

We have Playa installed on our site and I wanted to use it to create a Related Articles box.

Here is the code I have in an embedded template:

```
<!-- Related Articles Box -->
{if related_articles!=""} <br>
    <div id="related-articles">
        <h4>Related Articles</h4>  
        <div class="col">    
        <div class="cat">For more information about this topic see the following articles:</div><br>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="whats_happening|learn_more"}
            <ul>
        {exp:playa:children  field="related_articles" field_id="52" }
            <li><h3><a href="{path=library/article/{url_title}">{title}</a></h3></li><br>
            {/exp:playa:children}
            </ul>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        </div><!-- end .col --> 
</div><!-- end #related-articles -->
```

I know the parent template is calling this embedded one correctly because when I view Page Source I see my comments  and  but nothing in between gets displayed so it's gotta be a problem with this code right?

Thing is I had this working a few weeks ago and at some point it stopped working. I didn't notice until a coworker asked me what happened to it. The only thing I remember doing on the site was updating a couple of plugins so I rolled back to the previous versions but it still doesn't work now.

I can't think of what else to try. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your missing `dynamic="no"` parameter on the `exp:channel:entries` tag. However, it seems like you might be over complicating things as the `exp:playa:children` would work by itself if you pass a embedded variable with the `entry_id` of the parent to the embedded playa:children tag:

```
{exp:playa:children entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
```